# Ruby/Rails form submission to controller (twilio sms app)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, controller, twilio, twilio-api

I'm very new to ruby/rails so please forgive me for the simple question.

I'm adding SMS capabilities to an existing app for an assignment and I'm a bit lost.
I have created a texterController with the following code. In my actual file, I have my twilio phone number, SID and token number (just blocked it out here). The destination phone number and the text body are coming from a form and that's where I think the problem is.

```
require 'twilio-ruby'


class texterController < ApplicationController

  def index
  end

  def text
    number = params[:number]
    message = params[:message]

  twilio_sid = XXXXX
  twilio_token = XXXXX
  twilio_phone_number = "+1XXXXXXXXXX"

  @twilio_client = Twilio::REST::Client.new twilio_sid, twilio_token

  @twilio_client.account.sms.messages.create(
  :from => "+1#{twilio_phone_number}",
  :to => number,
  :body => message
  )
 end
 end
```

and here is the form:

```
<%= form_tag("text", method: "post") do %>
  <%= label_tag(:number, "Phone Number:") %>
  <%= telephone_field(:number, :phone) %>
  <%= label_tag(:message, "Message") %>
  <%= text_area_tag(:message, "", size: "24x6") %>
  <%= submit_tag("Send") %>
<% end %>
```

and routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'pages#home'
  get 'pages/home'
  post 'text', to: 'pages#text'
  get '/signup', to: 'users#new'
  resources :users
end
```

I'm pretty sure that the controller is not receiving the form submission and have been trying for hours to figure out what I'm missing with no luck. Any help?

Comment: "I'm pretty sure that the controller is not receiving the form submission" Well, is it? Does `text` get executed? What are the values of `params[:number]` and `params[:message]`? Also, it looks like you may be using a from phone number like `+1+1...` with two `+1`s, since there's one in `twilio_phone_number` and then another added in the call to `create`.

Comment: Shouldn't the route be `'texter#text'`, not `'pages#text'`? (I'm not a Rails developer, but I believe the first part of that string should be the name of the controller.) I also believe `TexterController` (capital T) is preferred, but again, I haven't written much of any Rails code.

Comment: Smarx is right. You should change controller pages by texters in routes. `post 'text', to: 'texter#text'`. And it's `TextersController` not `texterController` . Convention over configuration. Good luck for debug.

Comment: Aaaah that is it... took me hours! if you could add it as an answer, I can mark it as correct:) thanks for your help